# Is there a way, within my handler method, to determine which of the subscribed events triggered the handler?

Tags: symfony, events, sylius, sylius-resource

Assuming I have an EventListener tagged with more than one named event, or an EventSubscriber that subscribes to more than one event, how can I, within my handler method, determine which of the subscribed events triggered the handler?

In sylius, all the resource events use (a descendant of ) the Generic Event class.

I can see that the event name is not contained within the event class, so how can i establish which of the subscribed events caused the handler to run ?

```php
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'sylius.order.post_complete' => 'dispatchMessage',
            'sylius.customer.post_register' => 'dispatchMessage',
        ];
    }
```

UPDATE: I am aware that in this instance i could call `get_class($event->getSubject())` and at least know which resource i'm dealing with, I am however looking for a more generic solution that would work in any symfony project.

Comment: you can use Symfony Profiler and open Events tab

Comment: @Dr.X that might be helpful in debugging, but not something i can use in my code  'within my handler method' to decide which actions to take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more parameters passed to the callbacks than just the event object (you might come across them by calling `func_get_args()` inside your callback (`dispatchMessage`) quicker than in the documentation :-)). They're not mandatory but they contain what you might need.

The callback gets called with, as parameters :
- event (the object)
- event name (**what you're looking for**)
- dispatcher instance

(see https://github.com/symfony/event-dispatcher/blob/master/EventDispatcher.php#L231)

So in your case you can use the following :

```php
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        'sylius.order.post_complete' => 'dispatchMessage',
        'sylius.customer.post_register' => 'dispatchMessage',
    ];
}

public function dispatchMessage(GenericEvent $event, string $eventName, EventDispatcherInterface $eventListener)
{
    // Here, $eventName will be 'sylius.order.post_complete' or 'sylius.customer.post_register'
}
```

Comment: No real need to use func_get_args.  dispatchMessage($event,$eventName) will do the trick.

Comment: It was just a debug trick to see the "not so obvious" other parameters, not the actual code that should be used :-), gonna clarify my answer.

Comment: thanks Evanesis!  that was exactly what i was looking for... 
and @Cerad, your tip is the approach i am now going to use in my code, excellent! I wasn't expecting the first answer to be so on point!

Comment: @Cerad if you can flesh out you comment into a full answer, i will make it the accepted answer as it is the closest to what i was actually asking for... thanks :)

Comment: Let's see if @evanesis comes back and tweaks their answer.  They did 99% of the work already.  And it was in fact their answer that jogged my memory that $eventName was passed as a second argument.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I can edit the answer as it is exactly what I imply, I just got the bad habit to show where the explanation is instead of being fully explicit, got a bit rusty on StackOverflow :-)